# Add space checking to regex filter

Tags: regex, spaces

I have the following `regex` that is supposed to strip slashes and other path info from a file name for an uploader.

I also want to remove any spaces to the file name. I have looked at the other questions regarding this but cannot figure out how to add it.

what I have now: `/.*(\/|\\)/, ""`

Comment: So, did you use `s=s.replace(/.*[\/\\](.*)/, function($0,$1) { return $1.replace(/\s+/g, ''); } )`?

Comment: Please clarify the question, or it is solved with the answer below, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[\s\/\\]+` to remove all slashes and space..

`\s` represent's a space

`[]` is a character class which matches any one of the characters within it

`+` matches the preceding character 1 to many times